# Управление маршрутами и фильтрация товаров в каталоге

Tags: php, zend-framework

Добрый день! Вопрос такой, сейчас в SEO наметилась тенденция "грамотной" настройки фильтров каталога товаров. Настраивают это дело таким образом, чтобы при сочетании ряда фильтруемых свойств в URL сайт не просто передавались какие-нибудь параметры, например:

```
www.site.ru/katalog/telefoni/?brend=sumsung&min_price=3000
```

А конкретно формировался новый URL, полностью или частично, например:

```
www.site.ru/katalog/telefoni/brend/sumsung/?min_price=3000
```

Такую ссылку

www.site.ru/katalog/telefoni/brend/sumsung/

уже можно использовать в рекламных кампаниях, например, на Яндекс.Директ. Перейдя по ней, пользователь, по сути, попадает в каталог

```
www.site.ru/katalog/telefoni/
```

с включённым фильтром по брендам и цене.

Насколько вообще реально настроить роутинг в ZF так, чтобы первые 2 части URL понимались как обычно (`/модель/действие/` - своими словами, в ZF новичок), а остальные части как фильтр?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: новичёк -> новичок  
граматной -> грамотной  
на сколько -> насколько  
рекламных компаниях -> рекламных кампаниях

Comment: урлы жуткие у вас. Все что хотите сделать есть в документации и гигантском количестве статей.

Comment: Спасибо, КЭПЫ http://joxi.ru/n2Y813XI7ebxm6

Comment: @maler1988, ну честно, таким чувакам как я сложно читать такие тексты, как выше. Отдельный ад начинается, когда сам допускаешь ошибки и путаешь падежи, но это уже мой персональный ад.  
Держи :shipit:

![](http://pic20.picturetrail.com/VOL1621/8562246/15897778/242492034.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться классом `Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite`, пример:

```
 $router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();

    $router->addRoute('articles',
         new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('articles/:articleId', 
         array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'view'))
    );

    $router->addRoute('pages',
         new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('pages/:pageId', 
         array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'page'))
    );
```